# On image click hide the image and play the brightcove video

Tags: javascript, jquery, brightcove

I am trying to hide an image on click and display a Brightcove video.  I am not able to get the video to play once it is displayed.

Here is fiddle I created with the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/u9yvv/

Here's my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<div class="js-container container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="figure">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" alt="Image of a kitten" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="js-trigger trigger">View Video</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
  <object id="myExperience921449663001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="100%" />
    <param name="height" value="auto" />
    <param name="playerID" value="2079935931001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA1oy1bvE~,ALl2ezBj3WE0z3yX6Xw29sdCvkH5GCJv" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="921449663001" />

    <!-- smart player api params -->
    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
  </object>
  <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var player,
    modVP;

var onTemplateLoad = function (experienceID) {
  // get references to the player and API Modules and Events
  console.log('onTemplateLoad has loaded');
  player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
  modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
};

// template ready event handler
var onTemplateReady = function (evt) {
  console.log('onTemplateReady is ready');
  modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PLAY, onMediaEventFired);
};

$('.js-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  $('.content').css({ 'display' : 'none'}); 
  $('.BrightcoveExperience').css({ 'position' : 'static'});

  modVP.play(); //I thought this would make the video play.
});
```

I am not sure how to get the video to play once it is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried just simply adding this?
 `<param name="autoStart" value="true" />`

**EDIT:**
Your player has to be loaded for smart player modVP.play(); to work. The workaround for this scenario (where you're hiding and showing the player) is to create a short blank video without any audio that will be loaded in the background with your page. Then dynamically pass-in the video ID of the actual video you want to play. The trade-off being...it will seem like there's a few second delay before playing your video. Also,the css position off the page and then appearing may provide more consistent results than show/hide. Depends on the browsers.